# Converting to 1x11 SRAM drivetrain with 8/9/10-speed HG Freehub

Tags: shimano, cassette, sram, upgrades, freehub

I currently have a 3x9 Shimano drivetrain, and I'd like to replace the current Shimano 9-speed rear derailleur/shifter/cassette and front derailleur/3 chainrings with the SRAM PG-1170 11-32T cassette, NX rear derailleur, GX shifter, and a narrow wide chainring.

As I understand, 11-speed SRAM cassettes that use an 11 tooth small cog do not require the XD driver body. Additionally, SRAM 11T and Shimano MTB 11-speed cassettes are cross-compatible with Shimano and SRAM derailleurs/shifters. And Shimano 11-speed MTB cassettes fit onto 8/9/10 speed hubs, but Shimano 11-speed road cassettes do not.

The SRAM PG-1170 cassette is listed as a 'road cassette.' The REI description for the PG-1170 lists 'Shimano HG/SRAM PG' Freehub compatibility.

Is my understanding correct, and would this 1x11 upgrade be as straightforward as replacing the existing Shimano components with the SRAM components described above?

Answer (score 1):

> 11-speed SRAM cassettes that use an 11 tooth small cog do not require the XD driver body ... Shimano 11-speed MTB cassettes fit onto 8/9/10 speed hubs, but Shimano 11-speed road cassettes do not.

Basically correct. MTB cassettes with large low-gear sprockets can be made with the spider overhanging the drive side of the hub a little, so the longer freehub isn't required. I've been told on this site that some larger 11 speed road cassettes also do this and will fit on a 10 speed freehub.

I'm not sure this is a totally hard a and fast rule, so I think what you'll need to do is ensure that whichever cassette you buy will fit in a 10 speed freehub body

> SRAM 11T and Shimano MTB 11-speed cassettes are cross-compatible with Shimano and SRAM derailleurs/shifters.

Yes.

> would this 1x11 upgrade be as straightforward as replacing the existing Shimano components with the SRAM components.

The conversion should be straightforward. One difficulty may be finding a narrow-wide chainring that fits properly on your triple crank. Shorter chainring bolts are typically required to attach a single middle ring rather than middle and large.

Comment: *I'm not sure this is a totally hard a and fast rule, so I think what you'll need to do is ensure that whichever cassette you buy will fit in a 10 speed freehub body* I've dealt with this a lot and you've summed up the situation well. Shimano road 11spd cassettes need an 11spd freehub, except for the hubs that max out with a 34T cog. Non-XD driver MTB cassettes that one would use in a 1x setup will work with a 10spd freehub or an 11spd freehub with a spacer.

Comment: I believe crank bolt spacers can be purchased which will take up the extra length of the crank bolt. I bought some on-line to convert a Shimano SLX 3x9 crank to single-ring and was able to reuse the original crank bolts (from the middle ring). Additionally, it looks great (you don't notice the missing big ring)